# Moved character on swift3 SpriteKit

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit, touchesbegan

I have a serious problem, I practice, but Ball does not move. I also experienced this problem in another application.

XCode version: 8.2.1

Please help me. 
I can not make progress.

watching tutorial download the project; it's work!

I created in the course. it's not work!!

download my project : [Https://yadi.sk/d/TPN6OGrV3Gz7rq](http://Https://yadi.sk/d/TPN6OGrV3Gz7rq)

my code

GameScene.sks image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs9Gu.png)

GameScene.swift file

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var ball:SKSpriteNode!
    var paddle:SKSpriteNode!

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        ball = self.childNode(withName: "Ball") as! SKSpriteNode
        paddle = self.childNode(withName: "Paddle") as! SKSpriteNode

        ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 50, dy: 50))

    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to show the relevant code here and not make others download your project as well as better explain your problem.

Comment: It looks as though your ball is a child of SKScene_0 not a child of your game scene?

Comment: @LukeChase Yes, I tried them as GameScene and Scene and did not work. The example application also looks and works as SKScene_0.

Comment: Your download link for your project doesn't work. Theres not enough information here to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
```

to

```
if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
```

I ran your project on my computer and when changing that line the ball moved as expected

Comment: thanks @Ron Myschuk 
my code : if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
change code : if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")

and, its WORK :)